# I can't access my site using ip

Tags: php

I have uploaded my word-press site on go daddy server, and when i try to access site using ip address http://50.63.70.1/ and it's not opening any thing.

can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I don't know about GoDaddy, but I think you're not alone on that server, so you need to specify a domain.

Comment: have you updated your AR on godaddy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you paid extra for your own IP address, you are probably sharing one with other customers using name-based virtual hosting. So you simply can't go to your site by typing the IP address in the browser; the server only knows the correct site to send if given the name.

Answer (score 3):

A shared webserver hosts dozens, even hundreds of websites; all sharing the same IP address. The only way to distinguish one hosted website from another is through the [http host header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23). The browser automatically sends it when you enter a domain name in the address bar but not when you enter an IP address. In the absence of this header, the server usually shows the "default website".

Look at the GD control panel closely, you should find something called "preview URL". Use this URL to view your website until you're through with DNS propagation phase.

Answer (score 1):

Websites hosted at Hostgator can be accesed like this:

```
http://1.1.1.1/~cpanel_username/folder
```