# Trying to deploy a nodejs application publicly on my PC

Tags: node.js, http, ip, server

I'm trying, amongst other things to make the server work:

```
http.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1').
```

It works fine for that specified ip (localhost), but when I try to connect to my app from an outside client via my public ip, it doesn't work (doesn't load or even request the server).
Trying to solve this problem, I came across a post telling me my ip is not unique: [I can't access my site using ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257836/i-cant-access-my-site-using-ip)

How would I uniquely specify what to send an http request to, and more broadly, how do I serve a nodejs app from my own machine?

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is mapped to your **localhost**, so it wont work if you are expecting to call your server from outside client because using `127.0.0.1` from outside client will eventually call localhost of that particular client. So this will work for your machine only.
You need to provide **public IP** or **domain name** instead of `127.0.0.1` & use that public IP while calling your server from outside client.

Answer (score -1):

Well you have at least 3 options..you can use a service such as dynaip to redirect requests to your pc, or you can host the app on a platform as a service provider such as heroku or you could try ngrok, I am not familiar with that one.

heroku I believe is free for up to 5 applications, depending on usage.